# Сравнить объекты DateTime

Tags: symfony2, datetime, doctrine2

В базе есть таблица, одно из полей имеет тип данных datetime. Существует форма сортировки, пользователь вводит данные в любом доступном для класса DateTime формате, отправляет, мы их принимаем, на их основе формируем объект DateTime, цель - найти совпадения объекта с записью в базе данных. Всё бы ничего, но запись в базе имеет вид '2015-08-07 15:43:07', а нужно найти совпадения ТОЛЬКО ПО ДАТЕ, время роли не играет, LIKE использовать нельзя. Как поступить? (фреймворк Symfony2, ORM Doctrine2)

Answer (score 2):

Есть расширения для доктрины: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Устанавливаете через composer

Прописываете конфиг config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                dql:
                    datetime_functions:
                        DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                        MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                        YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

И далее запрос, например:

```
$now = new \DateTime('now');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')->createQueryBuilder('e');
$qb
    ->where('DAY(e.start_time) = :day')
    ->andWhere('MONTH(e.start_time) = :month')
    ->andWhere('YEAR(e.start_time) = :year')
    ->setParameter('day', $now->format('d'))
    ->setParameter('month', $now->format('m'))
    ->setParameter('year', $now->format('Y'));

$event = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение только по дате с использованием ANSI SQL `CAST`:

```
CAST(date_time_1 AS DATE) = CAST(date_time_2 AS DATE)
```